# Infinite loop scala code

Tags: scala, loops, pattern-matching, case

```
object Prop {
  def simplify(prop : Prop) : Prop = {
    prop match {
      case Not(Or(a,b)) => simplify(And(Not(a),Not(b)))
      case Not(And(a,b)) => simplify(Or(Not(a),Not(b)))
      case Not(Not(a)) => simplify(a)
      case _ => {
        if (simplify(prop) == prop) prop
        else prop
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm pretty sure I've an infinite loop caused by my 'default' case. I'm using recursion in all cases. Which is meant to be, but, only if the Prop can be simplified. As soon as the Prop can't be simplified, it should return the whole thing.

I don't see how I can test for any further simplification. (I'm not allowed to use other libraries, as suggested in freenodes #scala channel).

Can someone explain whether it IS the 'case _' causing the loop, and how to solve it? How can I test for possible simplification without making a loop?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to do two things in one step that need to happen in sequence—applying De Morgan's law (and removing double negation) and recursively simplifying any children. This is why just dropping a `case And(a, b) => And(simplify(a), simplify(b))` into your `match` won't work.

Try the following:

```
val deMorganAndDoubleNegation: Prop => Prop = {
  case Not(Or(a, b)) => And(Not(a), Not(b))
  case Not(And(a, b)) => Or(Not(a), Not(b))
  case Not(Not(a)) => a
  case a => a
}

val simplify: Prop => Prop = deMorganAndDoubleNegation andThen {
  case And(a, b) => And(simplify(a), simplify(b))
  case Or(a, b) => Or(simplify(a), simplify(b))
  case Not(a) => Not(simplify(a))
  case a => a
}
```

Comment: I see what you mean. Though, my assignment tells me explicitly to use a companion object. `Prop.simplify(Prop):Prop that returns a simplified and equivalent Proposition by repeatedly applying de Morgan's law and double negation ellimination to the argument Proposition. The resulting proposition must meet the requirements outlined below.` Also, your suggestion doesn't completely match my lecturers answer. (we have a system to run our work against a test) See: http://pastebin.com/WDuQKreD (also for full code at the moment) Thanks anyway!

Comment: @Sander: You just need to add cases to `simplify` for the other operations (also, I'm sorry I didn't understand that this is homework—I wouldn't have been quite so direct in my answer).

Comment: @Sander: Also, both inheriting from a case class and having a case class with an empty constructor are bad form. `trait Prop; case object True extends Prop` is better.

Comment: Do you have any documentation or some kind of example of how to implement the cases you're talking about into my `simplify`? (No need for apologies, I don't just copy/paste, I try to understand what it actually does). Thanks a lot! (:

Comment: You can treat `Impl` and `Equiv` exactly the same as `And` and `Or`.

Comment: Oh my! That's it, I totally forgot to simplify the arguments of the remaining Equiv/Impl.. How stupid. A million thanks!

Answer (score 9):

It is pretty obvious what happens and you are right with the default `case`. If your input `prop` does not match any of the cases you are invoking:

```
simplify(prop)
```

with the same argument. Because previously it caused recursive call to `simplify()` and you are calling your function with the same input, it enters `simplify()` again. So this is not an infinite loop but rather never terminated recursive call:

```
...simplify(simplify(simplify(simplify(simplify(simplify(simplify(prop)))))))
```

However the fix (based on your code) is simple:

```
if (simplify(prop) == prop) prop
    else prop
```

just replace it with...

```
 case _ => prop
```

Both branches return the same value. This is actually correct if you think about if for a while. You have a set of optimizations. If none of them matched your expressions it means it can no longer be simplified. Hence you are returning it as-is.

BTW looks like you are doing boolean expressions simplification using case classes. You might by interested in my [article](http://nurkiewicz.blogspot.com/2011/08/what-features-of-java-have-been-dropped.html) where I do the same but with arithmetic expressions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried to do so. (Sorry, pressed enter, and posted without wanting to). But in some cases the simplification result in a string containing a new Not(Not(a)) for example, so re-running simplify would eliminate these. But, I can't get it to run it again when their appears to be a new match on any of the previous cases.. :\

Comment: @Sander: can you show us the input that is not simplifying `Not(Not(a))`? This can fixed by calling `simplify()` on separate terms like, e.g: to simplify `And(Not(Not(a)), b)` you must return `And(simplify(Not(Not(a)), simplify(b))` (the simplification pattern is: `And(a, b) => And(simplify(a), simplify(b))`.

Comment: @Thomasz `Not(And(Not(a),Not(b)))` This will first simplify to `Or(Not(Not(a)),Not(Not(b)))` as far as I can see. The code should re-run to eliminate the newly created Not(Not(a)) and Not(Not(b)).

Comment: @Sander: this is a special case of [De Morgan's laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws) and I think it is fair to write it explicitly at the beginning: `case Not(And(Not(a), Not(b)) => Or(simplify(a), simplify(b))`. Similar for `Not(Or(Not(a), Not(b))`.

Comment: @Thomasz: That's another way around indeed. But somehow it seems like it's not working 100% either. (http://pastebin.com/rK28yn2J). Looking at the other answer given, I think it's fair to first use De Morgan's, and afterwards eliminate the double appearances of Not(). But is this possible this way? Thanks again. (:

Comment: It doesn't work because the default case doesn't cover things like `And(Not(Or(True, False)))` because once `simplify` is called for the first time, `And` matches `_` and hence the whole `And` expression is returned. It is, however, rather simple to do the two-step evaluation given by Travis without defining a second method. One example would be `case Not(Or(a, b)) => And(Not(simplify(a)), Not(simplify(b)))`, the rest is up to you.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, default case is causing the loop.
`if (simplify(prop) == prop) prop` is problematic line.
You don't need to test if it can be simplified further because when you are in the default case all possible simplifications are tried.